# Cannot to print in for loop

Tags: c++, c++14

Below is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numboftimes, n, sumvalue = 0, strvalue = 0;

    cout << "Enter Number of Times You Want The Loop to Run: ";
    cin >> numboftimes;

    for (n = 1; n <= numboftimes; n++)
    {
        sumvalue += n;
        strvalue += 1; 
    }

    cout << "You ran the for loop: " << numboftimes << " times. \n";
}
```

I can't get a `cout` in the for loop to print out an iteration. i.e., 1+2+3+4+5 = 15.

Comment: Why not? What happens when you try? Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and add the code that's printing in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print each iteration in the loop:

```
for (n = 1; n <= numboftimes; n++) {
    sumvalue += n;
    strvalue += 1;
    cout << "This is the " << numboftimes << " iteration to print" << endl;
    cout << "The sum is " << sumvalue << endl;
}
```

In this way you can print each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

When you are printing the variable numboftimes you are just printing a constant value

```
for(int n=0; n < numboftimes ; n++)
     cout << n << endl;
```

You put the cout anyways outside the for loop which will output only once, and only the integer numb of times

Comment: Yes sorry since i was writing it on my phone.